# Package managers for Windows

Tags: windows, 64-bit, package-management

You might be familiar with [Ninite](http://ninite.com). What I'd like to know is if there are good alternatives to that software for Windows.

The features I expect:

- installs the latest version of software
- supports 64 bit installs where possible
- strips ads/toolbars/similar stuff
- provides a way to keep the programs updated after installation
- if I can add custom installers to the software, that's a big plus.

Any ideas if such a program exists?

Comment: Out of curiosity (I've not used ninite yet) which bullet points does it not do?

Comment: Ninite doesn't keep stuff updated and can't be expanded.

Comment: By using Task Scheduler, Ninite can keep stuff updated, but it nags the user every time it starts.

Comment: There is a program called chocolatey that basically *feels* like brew.

Comment: You should ask questions like these on softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: That's really constructive but softwarerecs haven't existed when I asked this question :-D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe [Allmyapps](http://allmyapps.com/) might be somewhat similar to Ninite.

In addition, the best application update-checker I know is [SUMo](http://www.kcsoftwares.com/?sumo).

Comment: Allmyapps is great, I'm looking for such software. Thanks!

Comment: SuMo: WARNING: Should you decide to download SUMo, please ensure that you download the "Lite" or ZIP/7z versions (find the ZIP/7z versions on the download page - the links with the 7z and ZIP icons - the "Lite" version is below that, where it says "Free of all sponsors download links", as indicated in the screen shot below).  The full version comes with a program called Relevant Knowledge, which is detected by most security software as spyware.  from http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-software-update-monitor.htm

Answer (score 3):

There's a few- it really depends on your needs. generally you'll need to install the app to start with, but for a [security bent](http://secunia.com/vulnerability_scanning/personal/)  Securia PSI is good. Lifehacker also suggested 2 others in their [package manager roundup](http://lifehacker.com/5384140/five-best-software-update-tools)

Comment: Well, Secunia PSI is good, but that's really not for initial software installations. I'll look at the Lifehacker ones, thanks!