# Is Ninite a trusuted solution for initial package management on fresh/clean install of Windows 7 64Bit?

Tags: windows-7, package-management

I'd like to re-open the question from link below, where several packages were suggested besides Ninite.com such as allmyapps.com.
[Package managers for Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/86462/package-managers-for-windows)

What I'd like to know is if they are all to be trusted to install in Windows 7 (64bit) so that the manager:

- Installs the latest version of software.
- Supports 64 bit installs where possible.
- Strips ads/toolbars/similar stuff.

The later two points from previous questions are good but not a priority in the preparation of a clean install

- Provides a way to keep the programs updated after installation.
- If I can add custom installers to the software, that's a big plus.

I am more concerned here about using a legitimate application I can trust to establish the basis of clean image of my operating system with all the application of choice installed without fuss and spam/bloatware.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll try and dissect each point to make things a little easier.

In regards to Ninite:

> installs the latest version of
>   software

Yes. Ninite will install the latest (stable) releases of software.

> supports 64 bit installs where
>   possible

Definitely. From Ninite's page - *Ninite checks your PC's language and 64-bit support
to install the latest, best version of each program.*

> strips ads/toolbars/similar stuff

Yes. Ninite installs apps with the default settings and says **No** to toolbars and other junk where possible. I've tested it with Java and no toolbar was installed. To quote the Ninite website - *Ninite installs software fast with default settings and
says "no" to browser toolbars and other junk.*

> provides a way to keep the programs
>   updated after installation

Unfortunately no. The software is installed "as is". If the software (such as Firefox) comes with an updater, you can use that, but Ninite is not really a package manager in the strict sense, more of an easier software deployment tool. You may be interested in [Update Notifier](http://cleansofts.org/view/update-notifier.html) for this purpose.

> if I can add custom installers to the
>   software, that's a big plus.

Neither of the solutions in the other thread can do this as far as I know. If you are looking to automatically install other software not listed in Ninite on a clean install of Windows, [most installer packages include command line switches](http://www.appdeploy.com/articles/commandline.asp) you can use to silently install the software.

For great information on deploying software on clean installs, [AppDeploy.com](http://www.appdeploy.com) is a **great** resource.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and clarification.  I will install my anti-virus AVAST manually first before re-opening the internet after install.  Then Ninite will be launched to install the bulk of the applications I'd like to have on my clean install image.

I am familiar with silent and unattended install.  Ninite and the like just make it quicker to select for install a short list of popular applications, which greatly cut down the work.

UpdateNotifier sounds good.  If it is clean from spam-ware and works flowlessly, I'd use without reservation.  Thanks again John T.