# Is there something like apt or aptitude for windows?

Tags: windows-7, aptitude

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Package managers for Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/86462/package-managers-for-windows)

The most important features to me are:

- A mechanism to automatically update *all* applications I have installed in one go
- checking dependencies (like .net runtimes), installing them when needed and offering to remove them when no longer needed

Answer (score 4):

There is [win-get](http://windows-get.sourceforge.net/) (or [windows-get](http://sourceforge.net/projects/windows-get/)) which is claimed to be an automated install system and software repository for Windows; but I haven't tried it. On the project page, they say "the ideas for its creation come from apt-get and other related tools for the *nix platforms".

An alternative solution could be to use the free [FileHippo.com Update Checker](http://www.filehippo.com/updatechecker/) (247 KB) which scans your computer for installed software, checks the versions and then sends this information to FileHippo.com to see if there are any newer releases. Moreover, you can use [Secunia Personal Software Inspector (PSI)](http://secunia.com/vulnerability_scanning/personal/) which is a free security tool designed to detect vulnerable and out-dated programs and plug-ins which expose your PC to attacks.

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard of anything like this.

The kind of system you are after would require a central repository of software (or collection of repositories), and a standard software update method.

As each software author uses their own method (if any) of updating their software this is sadly not possible.

Comment: it might be sufficient to have a central repository of update mechanisms and dependencies though. But yeah, it would involve loads of work, that's why I asked