# is there any equivalent/branch of Homebrew for Windows?

Tags: windows, homebrew, package-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Package managers for Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/86462/package-managers-for-windows)

[Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) is a package manager for macOS mimicking Linux ones (think about `apt-get` as a canonical example). Obviously, it has some trendy features, like the total git integration.

however, I was asking myself if there was any branch of Homebrew for Windows platform and, if not, any equivalent (that's to say an apt-get like).

Comment: There's now http://scoop.sh/ , which is very similar to homebrew

Comment: It's definitely not a duplicate!

Comment: It's not a duplicate and http://scoop.sh/ should be the answer!

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at [Npackd](http://code.google.com/p/windows-package-manager/). I don't know how many packages it already includes, but I think it's that what you're looking for.

Comment: I think this is the new kid on the block, check it out:

http://chocolatey.org/